# How can I register a user in Keycloak via Google OAuth in NestJS?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, google-oauth, keycloak

I have a server on NestJS, I need a user to register in Keycloak using Google. How can I implement this? I already did Google Api.

I did it with PassportStrategy, but when I get the data, I can't log the user in because I don't have the password to create(). I configured Identity Provider in Kecloak, but the button appears in the Keycloak panel itself, and if I put a link to IDP Google redirect url in PassportStrategy in the callbackURL, it gives an error because it requires client-id (not Google's). Maybe I should make a client, but I don't know what settings to put for it and what request to write completely. Here's the response from Keycloak when I tried before:

2023-07-03 18:22:51 2023-07-03 15:22:51,862 WARN [org.keycloak. events] (executor-thread-59) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=7806201d-8bd3-48f3-809c-03a2dc2d1c93, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.18.0.1, error=identity_provider_login_failure

Started working with Keycloak quite recently, thanks for the help!